# How do I statically include a library in g++?

Tags: dll, g++, static-linking

As mentioned in the title, this is a real beginner's question.

I'm realizing that after several years of CS courses and projects and such, I have never actually needed to export an executable that someone else could run without compiling the source manually (which is what most/all professors/TAs do, since they want to see your source code anyway).

So my question is basically this:

When I compile some basic C++ code (e.g. "Hello World" code), I always seem to need some sort of external DLLs to run it.

- Visual Studio needs the .NET framework.
- Cygwin needs Cygwin.dll.
- MinGW needs libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll or something similar.

So how do I simply compile an executable such that I (or someone I give the file to) can just double-click it and have it run? I'm guessing there are some fancy command line flags I can use on g++ to statically link the DLLs; I have simply never needed to do this before.

As I said twice, this is a super beginner question, and yet I could not find (easily, anyway) an answer to this question, StackOverflow or anywhere else. Largely, I think, because the search terms are so commonly used in the descriptions for other problems.

Anyway, all help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I'm literally talking about a Hello World program. e.g.:

**HelloWorld.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try g++ -static -static-libgcc

Answer (score 1):

However, you should generally **avoid static linking**. Almost all the utilities on a usual Linux machine are dynamically linked: you can use `file` or `ldd` to know if an executable is statically linked. On my Debian/Sid system `/usr/bin/`  contains 7303 files, but only one is statically linked (it is `/usr/bin/rar`).

Using dynamic linking is better, because it uses less disk space, and most importantly because dynamic libraries are updated, and that profit to all the executables dynamically linking them.

If you care about dependencies, use your package manager (or distribute your program as a package).

Answer (score 0):

If you already got the static lib you need to link in, (.lib or .a), just put them together with the object files when you linking your application, like

g++ foo.o libfoo.a -o foo

I think your real problem is how to locate which static libs are required by your application and how to get them, maybe you should post your code here and let us know what library you need to link in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how: 
simply put, you specify to link all the standard stuff into your executable.

```
g++ -o c:\prog.exe c:\HelloWorld.cpp -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

hope it helps.